# Unable to decrypt AES encrypted string from Objective C

Tags: android, ios, aes, sha256, pkcs#7

I want encrypt and decrypt in Android and IOS and PHP.

In android and in PHP using

- Encryption type: AES
- Encryption Mode: CBC
- Padding : PKCS7Padding
- Hash Algorithm: SHA-256

when i encrypt and decrypt on android it works perfectly. but when I try to decrypt IOS or PHP encrypted String that is in Base64 or Hex2Binary. On android it decrypt string but first 16 character for IOS case and 19 character for PHP code it doest not decrypt showing other characters. I am pasting android code

```
            // Ignore this line this is for encoding
            //String input = "Congratulation, You've sucessfully decoded!";

            final byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            Arrays.fill(iv, (byte) 0x00);
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            // When I tried with this its gives "pad block corrupted" exception else work as above i told

            /*byte[] key = CommonUtilities.encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            System.out.println(key.length);
            MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit
            System.out.println(key.length);
            System.out.println(new String(key,"UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");*/

            // encryptionKey = "12345678901234561234567890123456"; Same in IOS and PHP
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(CommonUtilities.encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");

            // Ignore these lines these are for encoding
            /*ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            byte[] dstBuff = ecipher.doFinal(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));              
            System.out.println("encrypted: " + new String(dstBuff, "UTF-8")); 
            String enbin2hex = com.byte2hex(dstBuff);    
            String en = Base64.encodeToString(dstBuff, Base64.DEFAULT);*/    


            // this is Hex2Binay that IOS gives me to decrypt
            // Original Text: "hello shani how are you doing , Stuck in encryption ?"
            String strBin2Hex = "30BEF4AB063D0D72F91D8D11A7ADEE1B1EC58F67C4D9CC20F59FB56B8B23B7C665198CFF805897BD1AFB82E578AC82C6C18C0EA909E17540D0B95A81E8446168";



            ecipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            byte[] de = ecipher.doFinal(com.hex2Byte(strBin2Hex));  

            //de = removeTrailingNulls(de);
            //int bytesDecryptedAfter = de.length;

            System.out.println("decrypted: " + new String(de, "UTF-8"));
            // Decrypted String "igohj&t`hnh"kkr&are you doing , Stuck in encryption ?"
```

Here you can see unable to decrypt full string "hello shani how " missing characters.

In IOS using

- AES256
- kCCOptionPKCS7Padding

  ```
  // IOS encrypt code
  - (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
  char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1];     bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)




  // fetch key data
  [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

   //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
   //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
   //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
   size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
   void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

   size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
   CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                    keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                    "0000000000000000" /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                    [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                    buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                    &numBytesEncrypted);
   if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
       //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
       return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
   }

   free(buffer); //free the buffer;
   return nil;
   }
  ```

Any idea what i am doing wrong.

Thanks for you time

Comment: Arrays.fill(iv, (byte) 0x00) on Android; and "0000000000000000" on iOS are not equal. "0000000000000000" is equal to Arrays.fill(iv, (byte) 0x20) because '0' symbol isn't 0 code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I tried with 0x20 still same string. it does not give full original text

Comment: Means problem is in Initialisation Vector. Isn't it?

Comment: That's the first issue i see. Probably there are another like: no CBC option in iOS code, algorithm is AES128 but key size is AES256

Comment: I updated code of IOS any idea now

Comment: Remove all the "ignore this" code from the example. Make it clear that the iOS code is in a Category of `NSData` but better yet make it a standalone method and pass in the data to be encrypted. The if (to match) needs to be all 0 or 0x00, not "0" or 0x20. Get the AES key size the same on both sides. Hex dump the input and outputs of all all parameters and data on both sides to ensure they match.

Comment: There are two security issues. 1. Do not use an `iv` of 0.  2. Do not use SHA-256 to generate a key from a password, use PBKDF2 (Password Based Key Derivation Function).

Comment: @PetroKorienev for me it work with 0x00 for android and for IOS below code that you given. thanks

Comment: @Zaph can you provide me code for IOS for PBKDF2 Algorithm. and why can not I use SHA-256 (actually SHA-256 was requirement).

Comment: PBKDF2 is available in Apple's Common Crypto. Hash functions were used historically to create keys from passwords but that is no longer the best practice. PBKDF2 and other derivation functions should now be used because they have a build-in work factor parameter. That means it take longer to generate the derived key and slows down brute-force attempts and rainbow tables. See: [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) for a better explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the issues:

- Cipher mode (CBC in android code) isn't specified on iOS
- Algorithm is specified explicitly on iOS (AES128), and not on Android
- Algorithm does not accord to the key size on iOS 128/256.
- Initial vector is different

So, instead of

```
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                  keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                  "0000000000000000" /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                  [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                  buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                  &numBytesEncrypted);
 if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
     //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
     return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
 }
```

I would try

```
char iv[kCCBlockSizeAES128 + 1]; bzero(iv, sizeof(iv))
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                  keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                  iv,
                                  [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                  buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                  &numBytesEncrypted);
 if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
     //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
     return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
 }
```

Ensure, that Android also uses AES128

Comment: Specifically in Common Crypto (iOS) CBC mode is the default. The key and iv must be the correct length for Common Crypto, there is no default padding.